# IndexOutOfBoundsException when setting text in EditText using TextWatcher addTextChangedListener()

Tags: java, android, crash, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a problem when change the text in EditText, my expected result is clear old text then set the new text that user input. After that, every working with editText is normal.

```
Exp: old text: 'abcdef',
     user press key 'k',
     expected text in editText is: 'k'
```

Here is my code:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
private boolean firstRun = true;
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(firstRun) {
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        firstRun = false;
        if(count == 0) {
        // Delete key or other special key
            editText.setText("");
            return;
        } else {
            if(s.length() > start) {
                editText.setText(String.valueOf(s.charAt(start)));
                editText.setSelection(etp.getEditText().getText().length());
            } else {
                editText.setText("");
            }
        }
   }
```

}

My code is crashed in case user paste a new text inside old text (it's not crashed if user paste from begin or end of old text).

```
Exp: Old text: abcdef
     User action: abcd(paste here)ef
```

The logcat is below

```
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: replace (-1 ... -1) starts before 0
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1021)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:441)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.widget.TextView.replaceText_internal(TextView.java:8442)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.widget.TextView.prepareSpacesAroundPaste(TextView.java:8250)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.widget.TextView.paste(TextView.java:8271)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.widget.TextView.onTextContextMenuItem(TextView.java:8036)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.onClick(Editor.java:2862)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Can you print the CharSequence s and also start end and count? and tell us what does it show

Comment: CharSequence s is the old text, start is the position that you insert new text, count is 0 if the softkeyboard is "delete" key, otherwise the count is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unintended side-effect of a feature that adds spaces before and after the text that was pasted. The big clue here is in the stack-trace:

```
08-14 06:18:55.977: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.widget.TextView.prepareSpacesAroundPaste(TextView.java:8250)
```

You've written code in the `TextWatcher` that sets the text to an empty string (`editText.setText("")`), but the code in `prepareSpacesAroundPaste` is expecting the original text. Hence the index out of range exception.

Solution: try doing your text replacement in the `afterTextChanged` event instead; you might need to have a flag set in `onTextChanged` that is referenced in `afterTextChanged` before updating your text value.

Comment: Thanks @CJBS!, I have finished this issue after 2 days from the day asked this question. Actually, I have tried many solutions around changing text in afterTextChanged or onTextChanged functions but not work. My solution is write my own custom EditText that handle the copy/paste event, then custom EditTextPreference using my CustomEditText. It's worked as I expected!

Comment: You're welcome, @John. You can accept this answer if it was the correct solution. Read more about accepting answers at http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 0):

The `addTextChangedListener()` supports only a single character change at one time. So you are getting the error. So this listener won't help you for multiple text being pasted at once.

**Solution**
So instead be tricky. Use **hint**.

```
yourTextView.setHint(oldPassword);
```

So pasting any key won't be a problem. Now you don't need `addTextChangedListener()` as well

**P.S**

Use password inputType in XML as follow

```
android:inputType = password
```

Comment: So, can you give me a suggestion to handle my expected result? "remove old text, and keep the new text that user input"

Comment: can you explain your scenario of it's use. Why to remove whole text?

Comment: Actually, I need clear old password and keep the new change of user.

Comment: Is your password visible in plain text or you have dots to make it invisible

Comment: Absolutely the dot. But, I don't care what it is, just remove it, and set new one.

Comment: and your problem comes when you paste multiple character at once? right?

Comment: No, you didn't read all my question, it's only crashed when the position that user pasting text inside whole old text. So, i think it did not like your first answer. And my code just listen the first time user changed the text. (I removed my listenter after that)

Comment: why don't you use hint?